# How can I use dir attribute for a certain language?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a wordpress website with a huge catalog. Some of the products' description is in English (LTR) and some of the description is in Hebrew (RTL). I wanna create a CSS code that refers the `dir` attribute according to the paragraph language. 
The current code is:

```
.woocommerce  p {
    direction:rtl !important;
    text-align:left;
}
```

However, in the case of English description, the code below messes up the paragraph direction. Can I use a certain CSS code for the same class, but differentiate the direction of text by the language?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The standard approach for this is to use the [`:lang` pseudo-class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:lang) .

```
.woocommerce  p {
    direction:rtl !important;
    text-align:left;
}

.woocommerce  p:lang(en) {
    direction: ltr !important;
}
```

… but it does require that you explicitly markup the language changes correctly using [the HTML `lang` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/lang) (but you should be doing that to aid screen readers, search engines, etc. anyway).